# inject activity context dagger 2.11 error

Tags: android

i am trying to inject the activity context inside ImageUtls class:

```
public class ImageUtls {

private Context mContext;

   @Inject
   public ImageUtls(@ActivityContext Context context) {
       this.mContext = context;
   }
}
```

AppModule:

```
@Module
public class AppModule {

   @Provides
   @ActivityContext
   Context provideActivityContext(Activity activity) {
      return activity;
   }

   @Provides
   @ApplicationContext
   Context provideContext(Application application) {
      return application;
   }
}
```

ActivityBuilder:

```
@Module
public abstract class ActivityBuilder {

  @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = {OwnerActivityModule.class})
  abstract OwnerActivity bindOwnerActivity();

}
```

OwnerActivityModule:

```
@Module
public abstract class OwnerActivityModule {

  @Provides
  abstract Activity bindActivity(OwnerActivity activity);

}
```

OwnerActivity injection:

```
public class OwnerActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Inject
    ImageUtls imageUtls;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       AndroidInjection.inject(this);
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}
```

AppComponent:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AndroidInjectionModule.class, AppModule.class,    ActivityBuilder.class})
public interface AppComponent {

@Component.Builder
interface Builder {
    @BindsInstance Builder application(Application application);
    AppComponent build();
}

void inject(MyApplication application);
}
```

I am not getting a relevant error about what is going wrong..Can anybody address the issue?

Comment: '@ActivityContext' and  '@ApplicationContext' are scopes or qualifiers?

Comment: qualifiers my friend..

Comment: can you post the code relative to your component?

Comment: yes, i have just edit my question..

Comment: Do you implement HasActivityInjector on App class and inject DispatchingAndroidInjector ?

Comment: yes i do implement HasActivityInjector

Comment: I think Dugger can not provide Activity context from AppModule because there is no reference on it. Try to remove Activity context providing from AppModule and remove context field from ImageUtils class(just use default constructor). Will this work?

Comment: if i remove context field, how do i inject context inside ImageUtls class?

Comment: now I just need to know does it work or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155829/discussion-between-dmitriy-p-and-tsiro).

Comment: Anybody has a solution for this?